# Cannot start spyder3 on Ubuntu 16.04: missing modules even though they are installed

Tags: python, ubuntu, spyder

After a bunch of problems with Anaconda, I'm trying to set up an environment for machine learning and DNN's on Ubuntu 16.04.3, without using Anaconda. (Mostly due to my gpu compute capability being 3.0 and the conda versions of tensorflow require a minimum compute capability of 3.5). If I use python directly, I can use a different tensorflow-1.5 with a minimum of 3.0 and my gpu is used.

Everything seems to be running fine on a vanilla command line, but I'd like to use Spyder with Python 3.6.

I have installed Spyder3 with
`sudo apt-get install spyder3`

That's fine, but when I run it I get missing module errors, even though I have the modules:

```
$ spyder3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/spyder3", line 3, in <module>
    start_app.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/start_app.py", line 114, in main
    from spyderlib import spyder
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/spyder.py", line 88, in <module>
    from spyderlib.qt.QtGui import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QSplashScreen,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/qt/QtGui.py", line 13, in <module>
    from PySide.QtGui import *  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide.QtGui'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/spyder3", line 3, in <module>
    start_app.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/start_app.py", line 114, in main
    from spyderlib import spyder
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/spyder.py", line 88, in <module>
    from spyderlib.qt.QtGui import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QSplashScreen,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/qt/QtGui.py", line 13, in <module>
    from PySide.QtGui import *  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide.QtGui'
```

These modules are installed for both python 2 and 3:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pyside.qtgui
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pyside.qtgui is already the newest version (1.2.2-2build2).

j$ sudo apt-get install python-pyside.qtgui
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-pyside.qtgui is already the newest version (1.2.2-2build2)

$ sudo apt-get install python3-apt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-apt is already the newest version (1.1.0~beta1build1)


$ sudo apt-get install python-apt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-apt is already the newest version (1.1.0~beta1build1)
```

Any suggestions on how I can get spyder working with Python 3.6?